# Как сделать таблицу шире окна

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть широкая таблица. Её размер должен быть шире размера окна. Автоматически её размер подстраивается под окно и колонки становятся уже.

Как сделать так, чтобы таблица выходила за размер окна, не сжимая колонки?

Comment: попробуйте задать размер в `px` или `vw` + должно отсутствовать  свойство `overflow` у родителя

Comment: Можно и в процентах, просто размер заведомо больший, чем размер окна.

Comment: Мне кажется, что здесь помог бы win-width для ячеек таблицы (в первой строке).

Comment: @br3t, размер таблицы заранее неизвестен

Comment: Тогда +1 к `min-width` в пикселях у ячеек

Answer (score 0):

Задайте ширину таблицы:

```css
#container {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 150%; 
}
```

```html
<table id="container">
  <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td><td>e</td><td>f</td></tr>
</table>
```

```css
#container {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 800px; 
}
```

```html
<table id="container">
  <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td><td>e</td><td>f</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Размер таблицы заранее неизвестен

Answer (score 0):

Можно абсолютным позиционированием, предварительно поместив таблицу в родительский блок c position: relative:

html

```
<div class="parent">
<table></table>
</div>
```

css

```
.parent{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}
.parent table{
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: parent же тоже будет по ширине окна. Ничего не меняется